# Hexo: wrong address for meta and img tags

Tags: hexo

**Problem**

After executing `hexo g`, the index files for all my posts have the **wrong img and meta tags**:

For example, this is what hexo generated:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://xxx.github.io/.com//06/02/xxx/xxx.png">
...
<img src="/.com//06/02/xxx/xxx.png" ...>
```

But it should be:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://xxx.github.io/2020/06/02/xxx/xxx.png">
...
<img src="/2020/06/02/xxx/xxx.png" ...>
```

So somehow the `year` property becomes `.com/`

*PS: somehow the "og:url" tag is generated correctly in all index files. For example:*

```
<meta property="og:url" content="2020/05/19/xxx/index.html">
```

**Configurations I Have**

_config.yml:

```
# Site
title: XXX
subtitle: XXX
description: ''
keywords:
author: XXX
language: en
timezone: ''

# URL
## If your site is put in a subdirectory, set url as 'http://yoursite.com/child' and root as '/child/'
url: https://xxx.github.io
root: /
permalink: :year/:month/:day/:title/
permalink_defaults:
pretty_urls:
  trailing_index: true # Set to false to remove trailing 'index.html' from permalinks
  trailing_html: true # Set to false to remove trailing '.html' from permalinks
...
post_asset_folder: true
relative_link: false
...
```

and the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hexo-site",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "hexo generate",
    "clean": "hexo clean",
    "deploy": "hexo deploy",
    "server": "hexo server"
  },
  "hexo": {
    "version": "4.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "hexo": "^4.2.1",
    "hexo-asset-image": "^1.0.0",
    "hexo-asset-link": "^2.0.1",
    "hexo-deployer-git": "^2.1.0",
    "hexo-generator-archive": "^1.0.0",
    "hexo-generator-category": "^1.0.0",
    "hexo-generator-index": "^1.0.0",
    "hexo-generator-tag": "^1.0.0",
    "hexo-renderer-ejs": "^1.0.0",
    "hexo-renderer-marked": "^2.0.0",
    "hexo-renderer-stylus": "^1.1.0",
    "hexo-server": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was caused by the plugins "hexo-asset-image": "^1.0.0" and "hexo-asset-link": "^2.0.1".

It is solved by removing them from the `package.json` file, and installing the plugin from https://github.com/cocowool/hexo-image-link.